# android app is unable to debug in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-debug

I am trying to debug my android app in eclipse but I am not able to do so.
I know this question is asked many time. I have try almost all things but still cant debug my app.
I have `android:debuggable="true"` in AndroidManiefest.xml as well as having Category launcher and action main in Android AndroidManiefest.
Kindly Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elaborate the question please. What exactly can't you debug ? Are you using breakpoints ?

Comment: yes @Traxex1909... Debugger is not attached with the app when I click on debugg rather it simply run my app.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a very similar problem by using the DDMS perspective.  Once in DDMS, I would start my application on my device.  I then selected my application process and clicked the "Debug selected process" button.

Answer (score 0):

Restore to defaults in Run/Debug options.